# $XAUTHORITY in systemd

Tags: environment-variables, systemd

I would like to know if there's a way to use $XAUTHORITY variable in systemd, basically, I have tried to create a simlink between $XAUTHORITY location and ~/.Xauthority by placing it in a script and launching the script at start-up with systemd, but that doesn't work.

After further testing (with `echo $XAUTHORITY > debug` and `echo $PATH > debug`), it shows that $PATH (for instance) can be used with systemd and not $XAUTHORITY.

One of the service files used (to understand why it didn't work) is the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Create .Xauthority file in home
Requires=display-manager.service
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo $XAUTHORITY > /home/john/debug'
```

This ExecStart initially was ln -fs $XAUTHORITY /home/john/.Xauthority but since it didn't work I tried with echo $XAUTHORITY and $PATH

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I want it in multi-user.target as I would like that simlink to be created before the start of other services whose author put in that group and that make use of Xauthority, for instance with the line:

```
Environment="DISPLAY=:0" "XAUTHORITY=/home/%i/.Xauthority"
```

([service file for Thinkpad Yoga scripts](https://github.com/admiralakber/thinkpad-yoga-scripts/blob/master/systemd/wacom-proximity%40.service))

Thanks!